# Trouble with one command

Tags: command-line

I was read this article in EFY times: http://www.efytimes.com/e1/fullnews.asp?edid=111978
and I put twice the command:

```
echo 'man `ls /usr/bin | shuf -n 1`' >> ~/.bashrc
```

and now always when I open my terminal appears twice random commands.

And after I put the command:

```
echo dman `ls /usr/bin | shuf -n 1`’ >> ~/.bashrc
```

and now when I open my terminal appears:

```
The program dman dont be installed you can install it write 
sudo apt-get install bikeshed
```

but I dont want install it.

How I can erase all this when I open my terminal?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this kind of commands in terminal:

```
echo '<command>' >> ~/.bashrc
```

you add a new line with `<command>` at the end of `~/.bashrc` file. So you need to edit `~/.bashrc` file and remove the lines from the end of the file with the commands added. To edit `~/.bashrc` just type the following command in terminal:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: @vasa1 Sorry, no!

Comment: solved!!! thank you very much a lots Radu Rădeanu